Inconsistency in Time Reversal between Langevin and Fokker-Planck Equations
I am studying the relationship between the Langevin and Fokker-Planck equations, and I have encountered a puzzling inconsistency. I would appreciate an explanation for the cause of this discrepancy.
First, consider the following Langevin equation:
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = A(x) + \xi(t),
$$
where $\xi(t)$ satisfies
$$
\langle \xi(t) \rangle = 0,\quad
\langle \xi(t) \xi(t') \rangle = 2D \delta(t - t').
$$
In this case, the corresponding Fokker-Planck equation is given by
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( -A(x) + D \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right) P.
$$
The derivation is in here, for example.
Now, let us consider time reversal. If we replace $x(t)$ with $x(-t)$, the Langevin equation becomes
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = -A(x) - \xi(-t).
$$
Since $-\xi(-t)$ has the same distribution as $\xi(t)$, we can write
$$
\frac{dx}{dt} = -A(x) + \xi(t).
$$
In other words, under time reversal, $A(x)$ is effectively replaced with $-A(x)$.
The Fokker-Planck equation derived from this reversed Langevin equation is
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( A(x) + D \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right) P.
$$
However, the time-reversed form of the original Fokker-Planck equation is
$$
\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( -A(x) + D \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \right) P.
$$
This results in an inconsistency. What could be the reason for this discrepancy?

Can you describe why $-\xi(-t)$ has the same distribution as $\xi(t)$ more explicitly?
Also, the hint might be somewhere in Ito's lemma!

The noise term $\xi(t)$ has a symmetric distribution around zero and no time correlation. These imply that $\xi(t)$ and $-\xi(-t)$ follow the same probability distribution. More explicitly, $$\langle -\xi(-t) \rangle = 0, \quad \langle (-\xi(-t))(-\xi(-t')) \rangle = 2D\delta(t'-t)$$.

While I agree with $\langle -\xi(t) \rangle = 0$ due to the symmetry of the distribution. I don't know if you can say the same about $t \rightarrow -t$. You have to think about white noise as a differential of Wiener's process, $dW(t) = \xi(t)dt$, to make the argument mathematically meaningful. Now the question would have to be: Is $dW(-t)$ also a white noise? I think the answer to this question is more non-trivial than simple time-reversal.

In order to clarify note that $dW(t) = \xi(t) dt$. When you consider the transformation $t \rightarrow -t$, we have $dW(-t) = -\xi(-t) dt$. Therefore, to prove $-\xi(-t) = \xi(t)$ is equivalent to saying $dW(-t) = dW(t)$. So whether the last equation is true or not needs proving!

Welcome! I also coincide with @user35952 that you need to give more details on what  $\xi(-t)$ is. Is the process even defined for $t<0$ ? What is the initial condition then? Maybe a more sensible way to define the time-reversal transformation is to consider the process in a time window, $t\in [0,T]$, then apply the transformation $t\to T-\tau$ for $\tau \in [0,T]$. I think this proposed transformation will be easier to understand.

Firstly, there is a fundamental issue in your consideration that $\xi(t) = -\xi(-t)$.
In order to understand this, Let's define everything in the framework of Wiener's process. If $W(t)$ is the Wiener's process, then according to the formulation of your problem, we have $dW(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2D}} \xi(t) dt$.
When you consider the time-reversal transformation $t \rightarrow -t$
we have $dW(−t)=−\frac{1}{\sqrt{2D}}\xi(−t)dt$
Therefore, to prove $−\xi(−t)=\xi(t)$ is equivalent to saying $dW(−t)=dW(t)$, which is not neccessarily true!
Please note that $-dW(t)$ can be shown to be a Wiener process, but that is not the case for $dW(-t)$.
The second fallacy in your derivation is that Time-reversed Fokker-Planck equation is simply considered by taking the $t \rightarrow -t$ of the original FPE. This is False!
Please note that the Fokker-Planck equation is also referred to as the Kolmogrov Forward equation (KFE) and is only defined for $t > 0$ (check this). The accurate description of the negative time can be considered using a Kolmogrov Backward equation (KBE) (explained here).
In your case of the SDE, the KBE formulation leads to the equation of the form
$$
- \frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial t} = A(x) \frac{\partial p(x,t)}{\partial x} + D \frac{\partial^2 p(x,t)}{\partial x^2}
$$
